# Hough transform: difference in cartesian to polar equation

Tags: computer-vision

According to Wikipedia and most other resources on the internet, the relation between cartesian coordinate and polar coordinate parameters are described by the equation $x\cos{\theta}+y\sin{\theta}=d$.

However, the computer vision course in Udacity used $x\cos{\theta}-y\sin{\theta}=d$ instead, as shown in this short video https://youtu.be/2oGYGXJfjzw?t=4s.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no fundamental difference.  The difference is merely one of convention, namely, where you consider the origin to be in your $(x,y)$ coordinates.  If you consider $(0,0)$ to be in the upper-left (with increasing $y$ values corresponding to going downwards), use one formula.  If you consider $(0,0)$ to be in the lower-left (with increasing $y$ values corresponding to going upwards), use the other.  Ultimately, the two are equivalent, up to a flip of the plane (reflection across the x axis).

Comment: Does that mean that in computer vision, the second equation should be used since the origin is at the upper left in an image?

Answer (score 0):

I've been told that if you define theta as becoming bigger when you go from the x axis to the y axis you can use "regular" formulas instead of special formulas for when the y axis points down.